# Range of Object _Global failed?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code.

```
Sub Hide_Column()
Range("A,C:AV,AY:BA,BJ:BR").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

I'm running this from my personal in my active workbook. Thoughts?

Comment: `Range("A1,C1:AV1,AY1:BA1,BJ1:BR1").Columns.Hidden = True` or `Range("A:A,C:AV,AY:BA,BJ:BR").Columns.Hidden = True`  You don't need the `Select`

Comment: Thanks Tim. Still get the same error though.

Comment: Tim has correctly anaswered your question (+1 on the comment), unless you have further information to provide. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Update your question to add the new code which still doesn't work. If you're still having problems then you'll need to provide a few more details.

Comment: @TimWilliams As I have said a few times before, you don't always do yourself justice by posting complete answers as comments.

Comment: @brettdj - I'm a bit lazy, and it takes much less time to write a comment than a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when selecting a column, without using row numbers, a start and end must be given.

`range("A")` is incorrect

`range("A:A")` is the correct format

so your code should look like:

```
range("A:A,C:AV,AY:BA,BJ:BR").Columns.Hidden=true
```

Comment: That is the same response that Tim already gave so I'm not clear why it now works.